# Questions related to problems from Polya-Szego's book

Tags: real-analysis, problem-solving

In the last few days I solved some problems from Polya-Sego's book but right now I think that the formulation of some problems is slightly confusing and nonstandard. That is why I am opening this post and want to clarify some moments.

**Question 1.**

[image]

Suppose that $A_n$ are partial sums of series $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ and $l=\liminf \limits_{n\to \infty}A_n, \ L=\limsup \limits_{n\to \infty}A_n$.

Then we have to show $\{A_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is everywhere dense in $[l,L]$, right?
But usually when we trying to prove that $A$ is dense in $X$ we mean that $A\subset X$, right?

But here some elements of $\{A_n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ may be outside of $[l,L]$. And it seems to me a bit confusing.

**Question 2.**

[image]

The phrasing of this question is vague.

1. Is the limit point of a sequence same as limit point of set? In other words, $p$ is a limit point of a sequence $\{t_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ if for any $\epsilon>0$ one can find $t_N$ such that $0<|t_N-p|<\epsilon$, right?
2. If we take $\nu_n=n$ then $\dfrac{\nu_n}{n+\nu_n}=\frac{1}{2}$ and we see that the limit point of that sequence is empty.

So I would be very happy if someone can clarify my thoughts, please.

Comment: Do you just need the clarification of the concept or the proof to the problems?

Comment: @Hans, I need the clarification of the concepts. I don't need the proofs since I've solved them.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1. A set is everywhere dense on an interval if and only if every subinterval of the original interval contains a point of the given set. So the set can have elements outside of the interval.

Question 2.

1. The limit points of the set of the numbers of the sequence is necessarily the limit points of the sequence. But the converse is not generally true because the sequence may repeat infinitely many times a same number.
2. $\frac12$ is the limit point of this sequence. But the limit point set of its image set is empty, as you say.

Comment: I read your answer. Let's discuss question 1. Your definition of density is a bit weird. Why? Let me briefly explain it: The following is a classical definition of density. Suppose $X$ is a topological space with topology $\tau$. A subset $A$ of $X$ is called dense in $X$ if for any $x\in X$ and any open set $O\in \tau$ containing $x$ there is an $a\in A$ such that $a\in O$. I don't see how your definition relates with this one. This definition requires $A$ to be the subset of $X$.

Comment: Also I have questions related with your answer to question 2. But let's discuss firstly what I wrote above.

Comment: @ZFR: I see your point. Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_first_set_theory_article#Everywhere_dense the definition of being everywhere dense for $R^1$ which is the case we are dealing with here. It is a bit difficult to generalize the concept to the general topology.

Comment: Yes but this definition was given by Cantor many years ago. However, it does not coincide with topological definition. So your explanation is not rigorous enough, I think. However it is really close.

Comment: Rigorous means definitiveness in logic. This definition is definite therefore rigorous (with respect to the interval topology on $R$). It is not coinciding with the definition of the dense set. But why can you not treat "everywhere dense" as slightly different from "dense" where the former is defined only for the interval topology for $R$ while the latter is defined for the general topology?

You said you had questions regarding Question 2. We can discuss those too.

Comment: @ZFR: Do you have any response regarding mine above? You said you had question regarding my answer to Question 2. Are you going to raise them?

Comment: sorry I have been busy the last few days. Can we discuss your comment now? I still can give you bounty.

Comment: Hello! Please let me know can we discuss it? I have some questions about your post and I'd like to discuss them.

Comment: @ZFR: Let us discuss.

Answer (score -1):

1. "A is dense in X" means that $\overline{A} = X$. The closure of A is X. An equivalent statement is "for all  $\epsilon > 0$, and $x \in X$, there exists a $a \in A$ such that $|x - a| < \epsilon$". Here, a depends on $\epsilon$ and $x$.
2. How many $A_{n}$ can lies outside of $[l,L]$?
3. $x$ is a limit point of the set A if for every neighborhood of x contains an ement of A that is not x. Notice how a limit point is defined for a set as opposed to a sequence. It make sense to talk about cluster points of sequences. The set ${1}$ has no limit point in $\mathbb{R}$ but the sequence $(1/2)_{n \geq 1}$ has a cluster point $1$.

Comment: 1. But $A$ should be a subset of $X$, right? 2. Only finitely many. So what? But by definition of density all $A_n$ should be subset of $[l,L]$.

Comment: Yes, A should be a subset of X if it is dense in X. However, A is a subset of X does not mean that A is dense in X.

Comment: I know this. Do you see my point? Let me explain my question again: we are trying to show that $\{A_n\}$ id sense in $[l,L]$? But how we can talk about density when some of $A_n$'s are not even of $[l,L]$. Please read my question carefully.